# how can i add document values depending on day createdAt in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to add a value present in the "value" property of each document that createdAt is the current day, that the document has a "finished" property as true, and that the document has a "value" and "period.check_out" property.

So far, I have been able to select all documents that have the "period.check_out" property and sum the values. The problem is selecting the documents of the current day. I've tried to sort by day in many ways, but I'm not getting.

I enabled nas database models, so whenever I create a new document, it automatically adds me a createdAt, updatedAt and _v.

document example:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "1",
        "client": {
            "name": "raul germano"
        },
        "parking": {
            "_id": "5d8bfe395e0a822b143fd68d",
            "value": 2.59,
            "name": "pro parking oficial"
        },
        "finished": false,
        "createdAt": "2019-09-25T23:54:32.802Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-09-25T23:54:32.802Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "2",
        "client": {
            "name": "raul vitor"
        },
        "parking": {
            "_id": "5d8bfe395e0a822b143fd68d",
            "value": 2.32,
            "name": "pro parking oficial"
        },
        "period": {
            "check_in": {
                "user": "caboco",
                "moment": "2019-09-25T00:05:36.273Z"
            },
            "check_out": {
                "user": "outro caboco",
                "moment": "2019-09-25T00:09:56.506Z"
            }
        },
        "hours": 0.07,
        "value": 0.17,
        "finished": true,
        "createdAt": "2019-09-26T23:54:33.463Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-09-26T23:54:33.463Z"
    },
    {
        "_id": "3",
        "client": {
            "name": "raul germano"
        },
        "parking": {
            "_id": "5d8bfe395e0a822b143fd68d",
            "value": 2.60,
            "name": "pro parking oficial"
        },
        "finished": true,
        "createdAt": "2019-09-25T23:54:33.463Z",
        "updatedAt": "2019-09-25T23:54:33.463Z",
        "period": {
            "check_in": {
                "user": "caboco",
                "moment": "2019-09-25T00:05:36.273Z"
            },
            "check_out": {
                "user": "outro caboco",
                "moment": "2019-09-25T00:09:56.506Z"
            }
        },
        "hours": 0.09,
        "value": 0.23
    }
]
```

Current query:

```
collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            'period.check_out': {
                $exists: true
            },
            createdAt: {
                $gte: new Date("2019-09-24")
                $lt: new Date("2019-09-25")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: '$parking'
    },
    {
        $match: {
            'parking._id': Types.ObjectId(parking_id)
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: Types.ObjectId(parking_id),
            total: {
                $sum: '$value'
            }
        }
    }
])
```

That way he selects the last 24 hours

Based on the documents presented above, I need only the _id "1" and "2" documents to be selected. Thus resulting

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your $match with the following considering '2019-09-26' is the current date:

```
{
    $match: {
        'period.check_out': {
            $exists: true
        },
        createdAt: {
            $gte: new Date('2019-09-26'),
            $lte: new Date(),
        }
    }
},
```

What you are matching is: $gte: 2019-09-24T00:00:00.000Z, $lte: 2019-09-25T00:00:00.000Z. And I don't think that would be the current date.
Instead you need to match is '2019-09-24T00:00:00.000Z' - current time.

Comment: But "new Date('2019-09-26')" it's coming back "Wed Sep 25 2019 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)"

Comment: Okay. Then you need a work around to find the first second of the day which would be '2019-09-26T00:00:00.000Z'.